# What is the difference between `container` and `container.firstChild` in RTL

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

When I do snapshot testing, for example, what is the difference if I write in this way:

```
it('Should render correctly', () => {
  const { container } = render<MyComponent />; 
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

vs when I specify `container.firstChild`

```
it('Should render correctly', () => {
  const { container } = render<MyComponent />; 
  expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

I couldn't google any answers on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[container](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/6e6bf85301feed5d6bfa498d6d7f58a0bdef4520/src/pure.js#L46) is a new `div` element appended into [baseElement](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/6e6bf85301feed5d6bfa498d6d7f58a0bdef4520/src/pure.js#L43) element. The default `baseElement` is `document.body`. To get the root element of your rendered component, use `container.firstChild`.

You can found it from the source code of the `render` function.

```js
// ...
if (!baseElement) {
    // default to document.body instead of documentElement to avoid output of potentially-large
    // head elements (such as JSS style blocks) in debug output
    baseElement = document.body
}
if (!container) {
    container = baseElement.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
}
// ...
```

For example:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return <main>my component</main>;
}

describe('69027456', () => {
  it('Should render correctly', () => {
    const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('Should render correctly - 2', () => {
    const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Snapshots:

```
exports[`69027456 Should render correctly - 2 1`] = `
<main>
  my component
</main>
`;

exports[`69027456 Should render correctly 1`] = `
<div>
  <main>
    my component
  </main>
</div>
`;
```

The root element of `MyComponent` is the `main` element.

Comment: Where is this documented?